# Smarty counter doesn't work if array is splitted

Tags: split, smarty, counter

Is there a smarty function to get a counter in an array, but the array is splitted. In this case default smarty counter starts from 1 on every new page.

Comment: if you split an array you have more than 1. so simply calculate plus on count of all existing arrays

Comment: Sounds logical! But how can I calculate a counter?

This is my default code

{foreach name=aussen item=module_data from=$module_content}
{counter}
{/foreach}

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at the syntax of {counter} in the [official documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.custom.functions.tpl#language.function.counter)

You can adjust the starting value using the attribute start, for example if the last number of your previous iteration was 20, this will show 21, 22, and so on:

```
{counter start=20 print=false}
{foreach ...}
   {counter}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: I have already tried what you suggest, but that doesn't work. The counter doesn't remember what the last number of the previous page was and also doesn't know that there was a previous page. Therefore the counter always starts counting from start.

Comment: Um, well... smarty is a template system. It is not supposed to "remember" what you did in previous pages, that's what php is for: you can transfer information from page to page using session variables or parameters in the url and then passing them to smarty;